# Understanding convolutional layer depth in caffe

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

Im new with caffe, I have trained a concolutional neural network with 64 feature maps of 7x7, when I get weights of a filter y get a 7x7 matrix. However my second layer has 32 feature maps of 3x3 , when I get the weights of any filter I get a number of 64 matrix of 3x3 kernel for any filter of the second layer.
Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR:**
>
> The filters of a convolutional layer must matches the number of
>   channels of that layer's input.

#### Let's see an example:

So let's say your network receives 3-channel colored images (RGB, for example) with dimensions 128x128 (height and width of 128 pixels) as input. So the input to your first convolution layer (let's call it *conv1*) would be **3x128x128** (channels x width x height).

Now suppose *conv1* has 64 filters of size 7x7. In order to process all values from the input, a single filter must match the number of input channels being fed to that layer (or else some of the channels would not be taken into account during the convolution). So it must also be 3-channel filter and, in the end, we will have 64 filters of dimension 3x7x7 for *conv1*.

Conv1 will output maps of dimension **64x128x128** (number of filters X weight X height). If this is not clear to you, please check [this demo](http://cs231n.github.io/assets/conv-demo/index.html) [1].

And then the filters from the next conv layer (*conv2*) will also have to match their dimension to match the output. For example, 32 filters of size 64x5x5 (for filters with spatial dimension of 5x5). And so on...

*(For the sake of simplicity, we supposed that we zero-pad the input before convolving. Zero-padding is that "border" of zeroes that we envolve the input map. This means that the spatial dimensions, i.e. width and height, will not change. If there is no padding, then the output would be smaller than the input. E.g., for 7x7 filters with input of size 128x128, the output would end up having size 125x125. This decrease in spatial dimension is equal to the* **floor(filter_size / 2)** *)*

[1] [CS231n Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)